# Realm Migration: Migrate an object into a List

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

So, I've been trying to migrate my Realm schema, but I can't seem to do the following.

In the `oldSchema`, I have the following:

```
class Period: Object {
  dynamic var weekday: Weekday! // this is just another Realm Object
}
```

In the `newSchema`, I'm trying to move the Weekday into a List of Weekday(s).

```
class Period: Object {
  let weekdays: List<Weekday> = List<Weekday>()
}
```

When performing the Realm migration, how would I move the `weekday` object from the `oldSchema` into the `weekdays` list in the `newSchema`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a migration block under `Realm` Configuration.

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
schemaVersion: 2,
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

    migration.enumerate(Period.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
        // filter the versions where this change would take place
        // if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
        // }...
        newObject["weekdays"] = [oldObject["weekday"]]              
   })
```